# Nested LI in nav menu not displaying correct background color

Tags: css

I've got a nav menu that each LI has different background bottom border. Then I want each submenu to contain that background border upon hover. The problem is that I'm assigning background colors based on the number of listItems. And this is carrying over to the submenu, which I don't want. If you see, some of the submenus that have more LI's than the main menu, they have the correct background color after they've gone through the same number that main menu has. I hope all this makes sense.

Anyone have an idea on how I can get each submenu to have their own background hover?

Starting point: http://jsfiddle.net/trevoray/BgMAj/

```
   .nav li:first-child + li:hover > a {
background: #0f2992;
color: white;
 }
```

Comment: Sorry I'm a little confused on exactly what you're try to accomplish, you want the `li` nested ones to have the same color of the parent `li` ?

Comment: Right now, on hover, the nested ones are displaying all the header colors. I need them only to display the same color of parent LI upon hover.

Comment: Alright just give me a few minutes ill have a look.

Comment: Ah, I understood. When list is expanded all items have different bg color when hovered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply add `> a` the ID hover css:

```
#sub-members li:hover > a {}
```

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NotInUse/BgMAj/2/)